# Mongoose promises and bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

Will node ever have a builtin implementation of Promise or should we adopt one of the major libraries? such as Q/Blueblird? I have a code which uses async.waterfall and I want to move it to use promises. One of the chained function is mongoose findOne which returns a promise since mongoose 4.0 but I understand that it is bad practice to mix promises types, because mongoose uses it's own implementation of promise and I want to use Q/Bluebird. Should I use promsifyAll on mongoose? or will promisify will be deprecated once promise will be implemented in node
Currently the code is:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(done){
        User.findOne({ email: reco.mail }, done);
    },
    function(receiverUser, done){
        if (!receiverUser){

        } else {
        }

        // send the model to mongoose to get verified and persisted
        reco.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                //handle error
            }

            return done(err);
        });
    }
], function(err){
    if (err) {
        console.error('unexpected error while creating reco', err);
        return res.status(500).send({});
    }

    console.log('reco created successfully', reco);
    return res.status(201).send({});
});
```

I want to change it to ().then.catch() style

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you keeping the following way, at least I am using this method and it works. Please check the code examples below.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
//declaration
userSchema.statics.search = function (query) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    return mongoose.model('User')
      .find(query)
      .exec()
      .then(function(foundUsers){
        resolve(foundUsers);
      })
      .onReject(function(err){
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

//using
var UserModel = require('path/to/user/model');
UserModel
  .search(<query>)
  .then(function(foundUsers){
    //do something
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //so something
  });


//declaration
userSchema.methods.saveMe = function () {
  var user = this;
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    user.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(user);
      }
    });
  });
};


//using
var UserModel = require('path/to/user/model');
var newUser  = new UserModel(newUserData);
newUser
  .save(function(savedUser){
    //do something
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //so something
  });
```

Sure, using 'Promisify' helps in such situations as well, but a few times I faced with problems, so I decided to convert Mongoose promise to well known format.